# Is it possible to write different types of elements in the array?

Tags: c

I learn C programing now. Is it possible to write both numbers and letters in an array? Can you give an example if possible?

Comment: No, all arrays in both languages must have elements of the same type, unless you use `void*` which you should not.

Comment: Please don't add unnecessary tags. `C++`, `C#` and `C` are three different languages.

Comment: Please try to give more details what you are trying to achive and what you've already tried.

Comment: `char array[] = { 'a', '1' };` There's one possible example. Probably not what you want, but your question doesn't give much to go on.

Comment: *Is it possible to write both numbers and letters in an array?* Yes. *Can you give an example?* The Undead Fish gave one.  Another would be `int array[] = { 1, 2, '3', '4', 56, 789, 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};`. (I'd say both examples are perfectly useless, but they do demonstrate putting "numbers" and "letters" in the same array. A better answer would depend on what you really want to do. And if this is an assignment, it's hard to say what the accepted answer would be without knowing your instructor better.)

Comment: It may surprise you but the type of `'A'` is `int`, not `char`

Answer (score 2):

You can put different types into a union but you also need to remember what type you put in there. You can use something like this:

```
enum Kind { INT, FLOAT };
typedef struct {
    enum Kind kind;
    union {
        int i;
        float f;
    }
} Mixed;
Mixed m[1234];
```